# Expected maximum of a Zipf sample

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

A Zipf random variable $X\sim Z(\alpha,D)$ takes values in ${1,\ldots, D}$ such that a value $x$ is selected with probability proportional to $x^{-\alpha}$.

More precisely, $\Pr[X=x]=\dfrac{x^{-\alpha}}{\sum_{i=1}^{D}i^{-\alpha}}$.

Assume you have a set $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$ of i.i.d. random variables, each is distributed $Z(\alpha, D)$.

> **What is $\mathbb E \left[\max\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N \right]$?** (as a function of $\alpha, D$, and $N$).

If it is hard to compute, can we approximate it?

---

> **What if $D=\infty$ (and $\alpha>1$)?**

Comment: If $Z = \max X_i$, then $P\{Z \leq x\} = P\{X_1 \leq x, X_2\leq x, \cdots, X_N\leq x\}$ beyond which one cannot proceed without making some assumptions (such as that the $X_i$ are _independent_ random variables).

Comment: @DilipSarwate - you are correct. I meant i.i.d. variables, added to the question - thanks !

Comment: It's straightforwards to write down $F_M(x)=(F_X(x))^n$, so $E(M)=\sum_{i\ge 0}(1-F_M(i))$

Comment: @A.S. - true, but I need to be able to compute it in code, which is not doable when $D$ is infinite, or sufficiently large. I draw a random $N$ sample dataset and need to approximates the amount of memory needed for its representation (and the representation of each element).

Comment: Since we are talking approximations, are there any typical ranges, restrictions or relationships between $\alpha$ and $N$ (consider $D$ infinity)?

Comment: @A.S. - I need to create datasets where N range is 100K-100M, D ~ $2^{32}-2^{64}$ (which can be probably approximates as $\infty$) and $\alpha\in (0.8, 3)$.

Comment: Does such a huge $N$ make it rather impracticale to raise to $Nth$ multiple times? Also, it loosk like $N/D$ can be as large at $10^{-1}$ Is that correct? That makes $D=\infty$ seem like a poor approximation at the first glance. Also, for infinite $D$, your distribution won't have a finite mean (and hence no $E(M)<\infty$) unless $\alpha>2$.

Comment: @A.S. - the biggest problem is that summing over the domain $D$ is not possible for $D=2^{64}$. I'd like to create a synthetic dataset to evaluate some streaming algorithms. Real internet datasets are usually measured in hundreds of mega bytes, where each element is either a IPV4 (32 bit) or IPV6 (64 bit) address. They are known to resemble zipf distribution on normal behaviour (without any DDOS attacks for example). Skew value of $\ge 2$ is less relevant here, and is less often used for evaluation, as real datasets are usually more heavy tailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider $\alpha> 1$. We'll go far enough in the distribution so that $nP(X>j)$ gets small which will imply that it's unlikely that there are two or more deviations above $j$ and hence we can approximate $P(M>j)\approx nP(X>j)$ for large $j$ and deal with smaller $j$'s directly.

We'll use

$$E(M)=\sum_{i\ge 0}{(1-(1-\bar F(i))^n)}\tag 1$$

where $\bar F=1-F_X$. The following is a good approximation for non-tiny $j$'s:

$$\bar F(j)\approx\int_{j+1/2}^{D+1/2}x^{-\alpha} \, dx=\frac 1 C\frac 1 {\alpha -1}\left(\frac 1 {(j+1/2)^{\alpha -1}}-\frac 1 {(D+1/2)^{\alpha -1}}\right) \tag 2$$
where $$C=\sum_{i=1}^Di^{-\alpha}\approx\frac 1 2+\frac 1 2D^{-\alpha}+\int_1^Dx^{-\alpha}\,dx=\frac 1 2+\frac 1 {\alpha-1}(1-D^{1-\alpha})$$ is a constant of proportionality in the pdf. As soon as $n\bar F(j)$ becomes small (say $<\frac 1 {\lambda}$ for $j>L$ and set $\lambda=10$ for orders of magnitude), we can expand $(1)$ linearly:

$$E(M)\approx \sum_{i=0}^L(1-(1-\bar F(i))^n)+\sum_{i=L+1}^D n\bar F(i)$$

where we can further approximate the second sum by an integral  using $(2)$. $(2)$ also tells us how to pick $L$. We need to consider several cases - depending on how small $\alpha-1$ is. If ${n\lambda}$ is order of magnitude less than ${D^{\alpha-1}}$, it's enough to pick $L=(n\lambda)^{\frac 1 {\alpha-1}}$ which is especially nice (sublinear in $n$) if $\alpha>2$. I'll finish the analysis for smaller but not too small $\alpha-1$ a bit later. $\alpha-1$ so small that $D^{\alpha-1}\approx 1$ can be approximated by the case $\alpha = 1$ considered below.

Summarizing - compute the first few terms in $(1)$ exactly, then use approximation $(2)$ while $i\le L$ and approximate the rest by another integral that can be computed exactly. This doesn't work for infinite $D$ unless $\alpha>2$, since otherwise $E(X)=\infty$.

2. For $\alpha=1$, we get $$C\approx \frac 1 2+\log D$$
   $E(M_n)\ge E(X)=\frac DC\approx \frac D {\log D}$ which is intractible in your case as far as I understand.
3. Case $\alpha<1$ is even worse. Integral approximation to discrete sums yields

$$F(j)\approx (\frac j D)^{1-\alpha}$$

and hence, by doing another integral approximation to discrete sums in $(1)$ yields:

$$E(M)\approx D\Big(1-\frac 1 {1+n(1-\alpha)}\Big)$$

linear in $D$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In (2) -- consider $D=2^{64}$, $N=100K$ and $\alpha=0.8$ (the minimal skew I need). I'd assume the maximum would be **significantly** smaller than $D$. Where does this error come from?
+1 for part (1).

Comment: @RB I've updated the answer - it turns out we can extend my method from $\alpha>2$ to $\alpha>1$ - just not for infinite $D$. To see why $\alpha<1$ is so bad consider $N=1$. Then $E(X)=\frac 1 C \sum_1^D x^{1-\alpha}\approx \frac{\int_1^D x^{1-\alpha}} {\int_1^D x^{-\alpha}}=D\frac {1-\alpha}{2-\alpha}$ - linear in $D$. Basically for $\alpha<1$ the main contribution to the integral representation of the expected value of $X$ comes from the right tail - and hence the value is on the order of maximum. Intractible in your case, as far as I understand.

Comment: @RB You can also check that the formula for $E(M)$ in case $\alpha<1$ is correct by plugging in $\alpha = 0$ (uniform) and getting $E(M_n)=D(\frac n {n+1})$ as expected.